# What is the relation between variational infernece, variational bayes and variational EM?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

What is the relation between variational infernece, variational bayes and variational EM?

Answer (score 0):

This short answer assumes you are familiar with the basics of variational inference and also EM.

Variational Inference and variational Bayes are the same thing.

Variational EM, on the other hand, is a modification of the EM algorithm, where instead of the conditional probability *p(z|x)*, the approximate probability *q(z)* is used in the E-step.